# Tell facebook to ignore event invite notifications from a friend

Tags: facebook, privacy, notifications, facebook-events

I keep getting facebook event invites from a friend. These are events I mostly don't bother about. I'd still want to view the event details and all, but I don't want to get notifications regarding it.

I don't want notifications of events invites from friend "A", but I don't mind seeing such events in my calendar.

The actual problem I face is that I receive these notifications on the phone, and, I waste time looking at it. So is there a way to stop notifications from being shown, while still allowing for them being shown in my calendar?