# How to keep unaccepted events from going to my phone?

Tags: facebook, calendar, mobile, facebook-events

Now first of all, sometimes I do want certain Facebook events to appear on my phone, but only if I accept a request. Unfortunately, my phone shows every single event I've ever been invited to, even after declining. In the immediate calendar view, I've deleted such an event. However, when I ask Cortana "What do I have to do today?" it still somehow tells me about each and every event, so it's still seeing that event through Facebook. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the Facebook integration app on my phone, or a problem with Facebook itself.

Is there a way to configure my Facebook account to only push events to my phone if I've accepted them? Only solution I can think of is to block event invites from people who I wouldn't accept them from, but that's far too difficult to manage.

I've seen these two questions:

- [Tell facebook to ignore event invite notifications from a friend](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31380/tell-facebook-to-ignore-event-invite-notifications-from-a-friend)
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65711/disabling-facebook-event-notifications-on-mobile-phone

But those two questions are related to notifications, not to the calendar. It's the calendar I'm trying to avoid, because then the calendar gives me reminders and such, and gets filled with stuff I have no intention to attend. Again, I do want it to show in my calendar if I've accepted it.

I'm using a Windows Phone 8.1.